# How to store an invariant type variable in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I would like to parse the type of each value in a row of data from tokio-postgresql

Here is an example of getting a single value for a row of data from postgresql:

```
...
let rows = client
   .query("select * from ExampleTable;")
   .await?;

// This is how you read a string if you know the first column is a string type.
let thisValue: &str = rows[0].get(0);
```

In this example, it is known at design-time that the type in the first column is a string, and therefore the type for `thisValue` is `&str`. I would like to accept an invariant type.

I intend to use `std::any::type_name::<T>()` to derive the type name in `thisValue` and then use conditional logic (if/switch) to process this data differently depending on the type.

Is there an invariant way to store a variable in Rust? Will `std::any::type_name::<T>()` work on that variable? Is there another way to "box" the variable instead?

I understand that `std::any::type_name::<T>()` is using a kind of generics interface. To me, this means it's probably a compile-time strategy, not run-time. So I have my doubts that the way I am researching will work, but I hope I am on the right track and only need the final piece: an invariant type.

Should I be using `&dyn Any` and `TypeId::of::<TypeHere>() == thisValue.type_id()`?

In this situation, the `get` function of this API `tokio-postgresql` uses generics and doesn't return a boxed value. Therefore in this situation I may need to use `columns()` to determine the Rust type and the use separate functions to call `get` with different variables types.

The overall question still needs to be answered "How to store an invariant type variable in Rust", regardless of the specifics I have used to ask the title question.

Comment: By "invariant variable", you mean variant, right? That is a variable whose content may be any one of several different types? The way to do that in Rust is with an [`enum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html).

Comment: `enum` is interesting - I'll find uses for that - but not what I'm after. Thanks. The variant type could be anything, from primitive rust variable types to external library types (like enums and structs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **The preferred invariant type is `&dyn any`**

With `&dyn any`: [any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) is the trait, [dyn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.dyn.html) means the type of the trait.

Declaring:

```
let thisValue: &dyn Any = rows[0].get(0); //This works if tokio-postgresql returned a "dyn any" type, which it doesn't
```

Example of testing what type is referenced:

```
TypeId::of::<String>() == thisValue.type_id() //type checking using TypeId of boxed value.
```

Example of testing the type with downcast:

```
if let Some(string) = thisValue.downcast_ref::<String>() {
    println!("String ({}): {}", string.len(), string);
}
```

2. **Boxed**

[Box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/index.html) to force heap allocation (if necessary). This strategy is included too, so you can see how `&dyn Any` works with `Boxed`

A "boxed" value of `dyn Any` is invariant:

```
let thisValue: Boxed<dyn Any> = rows[0].get(0);  //This works if tokio-postgresql returned a "dyn any" type, which it doesn't
```

In this scenario the API being used requires generic inference, so for tokio-postgresql this won't work, but it is the answer for the title question.

An example of testing the type with the `downcast` function of `Boxed`:

```
if let Ok(string) = thisValue.downcast::<String>() {
    println!("String ({}): {}", string.len(), string);
}
```

**About the postgresql sub-problem**

As per the original post,

> In this situation, the get function of this API tokio-postgresql uses
> generics and doesn't return a boxed value. Therefore in this situation
> I may need to use columns() to determine the Rust type and the use
> separate functions to call get with different variables types.

So this answer solves the question, and although it won't work with the tokio-postgresql API, it equips you with the knowledge of the kind of API you would like to find/build/wait-for.

Comment: Untested as of now. if this answer is right, that's great. If it's not, it will help other responders understand the answer I am looking for.

Comment: you can use `downcast_ref`  for `&dyn Any`

Comment: Btw I haven't tested your code and used tokio_postgres but from [here](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.5/src/tokio_postgres/row.rs.html#174) `get` will not infer the generic type which implements `FromSql`. Therefore it will not able to call `T::accept` it expects you to write the return type explicitly.

Comment: Not sure about your real use case but if I am not mistaken to mimic the behavior above you can use the whole `rows[0]` as an invariant storage then you can test it with                                        
`if let Ok(string) = storage.try_get::<String>(0) `

Comment: Thanks @ÖmerErden. The answer is correct for the title, but not for my very specific situation. I wrote about this at the end of the OP - `get` uses a generic parameter in. My intention is to use `columns()` to drive control logic, and then call `get` with the supported type. `try_get` is another backup strategy that I might use. Ideally tokio-postgresql would have an extra API that returns `dyn any` typed result, but I am not prepared to build that at this stage.